# Mounting root filesystem while booting through network

Tags: arguments, root-filesystem, bootable, pxe

I have two systems, let say one is the server and the other is the client.

I want to load `kernel image` from the server to the client through the network.

I used `dhcp (isc-dhcp-server)` and `tftp (tftpd-hpa)`. At the server side, I made the necessary changes in `/etc/dhcp/dhcp.conf` file to assign the IP address to the client.

I created the directory`/tftpboot` and I copied `pxelinux.0`from the server. Inside `/tftpboot`, I created a directory with the name `pxelinux.cfg` and inside `pxelinux.cfg` I created a file with the name default: `/tftpboot/pxelinux.cfg/default` .

In that file my boot arguments are

```
default openwrt
label openwrt
kernel openwrt-x86-generic-vmlinuz
append boot=nfs root=/dev/nfs root=nfs:server-ipaddress:/tftpboot ip=dhcp  rw
```

And my question is, I am able to load the kernel but I am not able to `mount` the desired file system to the client while booting only.

What have I done wrong?